# jQuery to get background image height and change parent based on ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image for each item; in this case the image size is 580x374.

This is being set inline on the li a item for each as a background image but I need to set the elements height so it shows correctly. The image height returned I need to half as it's two images in one that I need to move position on hover but I can do that.

What I am having a problem with is getting the elements width, getting the background size, working out the ratio of the background image size and setting the height of the container to display it.

I need it to be responsive as well, so it sets right on page load whichever viewport size it is and resize.

Here is where I have got to so far, but I'm new to JS.

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
<ul>
<li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
 <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733" style="background-image: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733&quot;);">
  <div class="collection-list-hover-desc right">

    <p>Dein eigener Ruhepol in einer hektischen Welt. Der durch eine Struktur im Inneren formstabile Sitzsack vereint Komfort und Ästhetik.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-list-hover-button left">
    <span class="button">Entdecken</span>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
<li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
 <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733" style="background-image: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733&quot;);">
  <div class="collection-list-hover-desc right">

    <p>Dein eigener Ruhepol in einer hektischen Welt. Der durch eine Struktur im Inneren formstabile Sitzsack vereint Komfort und Ästhetik.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-list-hover-button left">
    <span class="button">Entdecken</span>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
<li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
 <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" data-image="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733" style="background-image: url(&quot;//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1839/7697/collections/category-panel-butterfly.jpg?v=1490985733&quot;);">
  <div class="collection-list-hover-desc right">

    <p>Dein eigener Ruhepol in einer hektischen Welt. Der durch eine Struktur im Inneren formstabile Sitzsack vereint Komfort und Ästhetik.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-list-hover-button left">
    <span class="button">Entdecken</span>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.collection-hover a').each(function (index, value){
  var collection_bg_img = new Image;
  collection_bg_img.src = $(this).data('image');         
  var bgImgWidth = collection_bg_img.width;
  var bgImgHeight = collection_bg_img.height;
  var divWidth = $(this).width();
  var realImgHeight = ( bgImgHeight / bgImgWidth) * divWidth;
  var halfImage = (realImgHeight / 2);
  $(this).height(halfImage);
  //console.log(halfImage);
});
```

I guess could set a max width and height and change it width whatever width is set by viewport and adjust height based on ratio?

**UPDATE**

I tried something like this, not got it working yet though... but maybe a good approach as would be a max width:

```
$('.collection-hover a').each(function() {
var maxWidth = 580; // Max width for the image
var maxHeight = 374;    // Max height for the image
var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

// Check if the current width is larger than the max
if(width > maxWidth){
  ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
  $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
  $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
  height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
}

var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

// Check if current height is larger than max
if(height > maxHeight){
  ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
  $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
  $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
  width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
}

});
```

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, you're trying to:  
  
[Add a div to a webpage, the width of which is unknowable]
 - [Add a background to that div and have the background stretch to the width of the div] - [Resize the div to 1/2 the height of the stretched background]
  
Is that correct?

Comment: The max is 580 of the background image which is also the max of the wrapper, i am setting the background-image on the element but not showing as i need to set the height of the container so my logic was to get the dimensions of the background image, half the height and then set based on ratio of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only :

- address DOM elements after the document is `ready`
- measure an image's width after it has successfully loaded.

Therefore :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function resizeBgImgContainers() {
        $('.collection-hover a').each(function() {
            var $a = $(this);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                $a.height(img.height * $a.width() / img.width / 2);
            };
            img.src = $a.data('image');         
        });
    }
    $(window).on('resize', resizeBgImgContainers).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Its not a set image in source, its being loaded as a background image...

Comment: OK, give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks mate, grabbing image, checking height, half it then set height of container... not sure how it would work / display if on mobile as ratio less but ill test from your changes and were go from there. Thanks!

Comment: Take another look. The math is what I understand from the question. I've not tried to verify it.

Comment: Thanks mate, i added var imageHeight = $a.height(); $(this).css('height',imageHeight); and seems to got me a little way there, is it possible to update on resize you think?

Comment: Yes, update on resize is possible. Give me another minute.

Comment: Thanks mate, good of you! guess need to get element width and change height based on ration so background image is correct size but ill leave with you! thanks buddy

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, your original algorithm was fundamentally OK. It's just a question of how/when to trigger it.

Comment: Cheers dude! i made a little adjustment but seems to be doing the trick: update here: https://jsbin.com/kuyumukifu/edit?js

Comment: I can't immediately see why those changes should be necessary but hey, when your back's against the wall, don't analyse it - just run with what works. Good luck.

Comment: haha yea, its 4am been at it since 7am.... and with going on holiday tomorrow going code crazy! thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this question correctly, you're trying to:

- Add a div to a webpage, the width of which is unknowable.
- Add a background to that div and have the background stretch to the width of the div
- Resize the div to 1/2 the height of the stretched background

---

### This can actually be accomplished with a combination of img tags and pure CSS.

Here's a JsFiddle demonstating that: https://jsfiddle.net/x11n48yz/1/

```
<div id='my-page'>
  <div class='image-holder'>
    <img src='http://cflrs.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/example.jpg'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#my-page {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
}

.image-holder {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.image-holder img:hover {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use image tag, the image is set as a background to the element

Comment: And why can't you use an img tag?

Comment: Because i have 2 image states, normal and hover and as its shopify and can only add 1 image for a collection / category i have to do this way... it sucks believe me but my hands are tied.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include support for the 2-in-1 image I think you're describing.  
[Roamer-1888's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43151861/1575348) is likely closer to what you're looking for but I'll leave this here for others who might be looking to do this using img/CSS.